# How to make a color transparent on actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, png, transparency

I have a png which has mainly two colors as background. I'd want to know if as3 provides methods to select a color to make it transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at BitmapData class.

You can [get](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getPixel%28%29) color of each pixel and [set](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#setPixel32%28%29) transparency for some of them.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the BitmapData method threshold :

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#threshold%28%29

```
public function threshold(sourceBitmapData:BitmapData, sourceRect:Rectangle, destPoint:Point, operation:String, threshold:uint, color:uint = 0, mask:uint = 0xFFFFFFFF, copySource:Boolean = false):uint
```